# C MongoDB driver - how to add Date?

Tags: c, mongodb

I feel like C driver for MongoDB is lacking examples that are beyond some basic stuff. I am talking about this documentation http://api.mongodb.org/c/1.2.0/index.html. Does anybody have an example of inserting a Date object to database or doing batch update of complete document and not one specific field like in example in documentation? Can't believe there is nothing out there, there has got to be people that still use C right ? :)

**EDIT:**

Ok It seams that people think I'd like to start a discussion which I am not so my question is:

How to add Date object in mongodb with C driver ?

Comment: With C being currently 2nd rank in the Tiobe index, one might come to the conclusion it is still in use, yes. But your question as given is OT, imo.

Comment: Lots of people still use C - me, for one.  But almost no one uses C for web services, which is where MongoDB is most commonly used.  It's a really bad language choice for that application.  When I wrote against MongoDB, it was in Python.  When I write for embedded microprocessors, that's when I use C.

Comment: I use it for parsing the files and db insert not for web app

Comment: The documentation of C API for mongodb is quite lacking, indeed. I agree with you on that. This is probably because C is not that popular for developing web applications.

Comment: Does anybody know if you can call mongoc_bulk_operation_update() with more than one field in document. All I found is using $set and one field in document to update so I am calling it in a loop. Would be nice if you can $set the new values for complete document at one pass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite lacking. The code of conduct here requires that you post the code that you try. Never the less, here is how to start.

First you need to know how to work with the C driver. Here is an example from the [mongodb-c-api documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/inserting-document.html):

```
#include <bson.h>
#include <mongoc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int   argc,
      char *argv[])
{
    mongoc_client_t *client;
    mongoc_collection_t *collection;
    mongoc_cursor_t *cursor;
    bson_error_t error;
    bson_oid_t oid;
    bson_t *doc;

    mongoc_init ();

    client = mongoc_client_new ("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
    collection = mongoc_client_get_collection (client, "test", "test");

    doc = bson_new ();
    bson_oid_init (&oid, NULL);
    BSON_APPEND_OID (doc, "_id", &oid);
    BSON_APPEND_UTF8 (doc, "hello", "world");

    if (!mongoc_collection_insert (collection, MONGOC_INSERT_NONE, doc, NULL, &error)) {
        printf ("%s\n", error.message);
    }

    bson_destroy (doc);
    mongoc_collection_destroy (collection);
    mongoc_client_destroy (client);

    return 0;
}
```

See the documentation how to compile this. 
Now, you have to understand, you always insert BSON docs, and the data type you want to insert, is datetime, so you probably want to insert the document with `bson_append_date_time()`. For more information  you would have to look in the [documentation of libbson](https://api.mongodb.org/libbson/current/bson_append_date_time.html).
I hope it is enough to get you started.

Comment: I allready have a file parser setup that works, what I didnt find is howe to add Date object to document and didnt manage to google decent example of this. Thanks for the bson_append_date_time() Ill study the link thoroughly.

Comment: Ok so I dont want to un-accept the answer since it gave me a link to search topic, but the main problem was that time needs to be specified in MILISECONDS not in seconds. https://api.mongodb.org/libbson/current/bson_append_date_time.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bson_append_now_utc to add the current time to a document.

```
    bson_append_now_utc(doc, "expire_time", -1);
```

Working snippet:

```
doc = bson_new ();
bson_oid_init (&oid, NULL);
BSON_APPEND_OID (doc, "_id", &oid);

bson_append_now_utc(doc, "expire_time", -1);

if (!mongoc_collection_insert (collection, MONGOC_INSERT_NONE, doc, NULL, &error)) 
    {
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error.message);
    }

bson_destroy (doc);
```